# Pivoting a Pandas Dataframe of Counts by Date and Group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
                            id_x  id_y
department         date               
0                  09/2017     1   NaN
1                  01/2018   149   NaN
                   01/2019   112   4.0
                   02/2018   103   1.0
                   02/2019    78   NaN
...                          ...   ...
799                09/2017    57   2.0
                   10/2017    64   3.0
                   11/2017    80   NaN
                   12/2017    79   2.0
```

This is the result of a dataframe constructed from database data where a series of counts were run and grouped by both department and date.

I need this data aggregated by both department and date, however, I want to have the dates span the top, followed by the counts of ids.

My desired output is something along the lines of:

```
                              9/2017      10/2017
                            id_x   id_y  id_x   id_y
department 
0                              1   NaN    NaN   NaN
1                            NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN
...                          ...   ...    ...   ...
799                           57   2.0     64   3.0
```

I've tried removing the index, reindexing, melting the dataframe, and pivoting the dataframe.  I can get the dataframe to order by "id_x" and "id_y" followed by the dates, however, this is not an elegant solution since it repeated potentially 36 dates over for each id.

I've been referencing the following document:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

And have tested variations of the following solutions (among others):

```
new_df.melt(new_df, col_level=0, id_vars=['department'], value_vars=['id_x','id_y'])
new_df.reset_index().pivot_table(index="department", columns="date") #I've also tried "date" as values and in brackets outside the parenthesis
```

Comment: I've also tried unstacking - again, it was close but the ids were in the first column header followed by the dates - ultimately duplicating the dates.

Comment: `unstack('date').swap_level(0,1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recreated your data but I think this gets you to what you need? 
If date field was actually datetime in your df, the sort would display the dataframe in ascending date order.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'department':[0,1,1,1,1,799,799,799,799],'date':['09/2017','01/2018','01/2019','02/2018','02/2019','09/2017','10/2017','11/2017','12/2017'],'id_x':[1,149,112,103,78,57,64,80,79],'id_y':[np.NaN,np.NaN,4.0,1.0,np.NaN,2.0,3.0,np.NaN,2.0]})


df=df.set_index('department')
df2=df.pivot(columns='date',values=['id_x','id_y'])        

df3=df2.swaplevel(axis=1)
df3.sort_index(axis=1, level=0, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
date       01/2018      01/2019      02/2018  ... 10/2017 11/2017      12/2017     
              id_x id_y    id_x id_y    id_x  ...    id_y    id_x id_y    id_x id_y
department                                    ...                                  
0              NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN
1            149.0  NaN   112.0  4.0   103.0  ...     NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN
799            NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  ...     3.0    80.0  NaN    79.0  2.0
```